# How to copy settings from a live usb ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

My ubuntu 12.10 installation has a big display problem ("gnome no effects works", but no other desktop option), how can I copy the settings from a Ubuntu Live USB (that works flawlessly)?

thanks

Comment: What hardware (video card)?

Comment: my video card is: intel GMA 4500mhd `lspci | grep VGA :  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)`

Comment: Somewhat similar problem - http://askubuntu.com/questions/60579/intel-gma-4500m-screen-resolution-problem

Answer (score 0):

Since **Ubuntu Live USB** works fine on your computer, probably something went wrong behind the scenes during installation.

If what you mean by "big display problem", "no other desktop option", etc. is that you cannot have a usable desktop session, I think **formatting the partition you've installed Ubuntu, and trying to install it again** might be a better option than trying to overcome this system (display?) configuration problem in some way.

Comment: As we do not understand the problem, formatting the partition and doing a fresh install is probably not the best next step.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I agree, and amended my answer to help a user who might not be able to give more information to provide the perfect solution... So many questions seem unanswered because of such situations...