# Intel mobile 4 series drivers with "nomodeset"-parameter

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. Since I couldn't start the installer and only got a "Black screen" I had to start it with the "nomodeset"-parameter.

The installation went fine, after rebooting the system I still had the "Black screen"-issue so I still have to boot the system with "nomodeset".

Now I'm trying to get the right video card drivers installed.
The questions are:

How do I find out my exact chip in the first place? (Since "Intel mobile 4 series" doesn't help me a lot here)

How do I install the correct drivers afterwards?

Comment: Does anything appear in Additional Drivers/

Comment: No it does not. But the problem is solved now.

Comment: Did you solve this problem, or did it seem to just go away by itself? If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job). You can even mark your own answer as the accepted answer, 2 days after posting it. This can help others searching for help with the same problem. On the other hand, if it seems to just have gone away by itself, please let us know--we can then close this question as "too localized."

Comment: The problem didn't solve itself, but since I'm new here I can't answer my own question within 8 hours after asking it =).
I'll answer it tomorrow if no one else does.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after tinkering a bit more and some digging here I found a solution:

It seems to be a problem with the LCD backlights. The built in intel graphic drivers are actually working, but it simply doesn't turn on the LCD backlight.

A solution can be found here: [Intel GMA 4500M screen resolution problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60579/intel-gma-4500m-screen-resolution-problem)

Instead of booting the system with `nomodeset` or `i915.modeset=0`. You have to boot it with: `acpi_osi=Linux`. This will allow the backlights to be turned on, but you have to do so manually via: `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00`.

To automate it you have to edit `/etc/rc.local` and add the `setpci` command.
The same problem appears after your system comes back from sleep so you have to add the command to the scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`.

It did the job for me =)

I hope I can help someone with my research.

Kind regards,
Apoc